# Shell Script, read on same line after echoing a message

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Following the shell script that I am executing

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter [y/n] : "
read opt
```

Its output is

```
Enter [y/n] : 
Y
```

I want that the variable should be read on the same line like below

```
Enter [y/n] : Y
```

Should be simple I guess, but I am new to bash scripting.

Comment: @Aaron

Thanks for formatting the post. It was my first post. I will ensure that my other posts are well formatted.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The shebang `#!/bin/sh` means you're writing code for either the historical Bourne shell (still found on some systems like Solaris I think), or more likely, the standard shell language as defined by POSIX. This means that `read -p` and `echo -n` are both unreliable.

The standard/portable solution is:

```
printf 'Enter [y/n] : '
read -r opt
```

(The `-r` prevents the special treatment of `\`, since `read` normally accepts that as a line-continuation when it's at the end of a line.)

If you know that your script will be run on systems that have Bash, you can change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) and use all the fancy Bash features. (Many systems have `/bin/sh` symlinked to `bash` so it works either way, but relying on that is bad practice, and `bash` actually disables some of its own features when executed under the name `sh`.)

Comment: That's a great and very clear explanation. I am on RHEL 5.5 BTW.

Answer (score 72):

Solution: `read -p "Enter [y/n] : " opt`

From `help read`:

```
  -p prompt output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
        attempting to read
```

Answer (score 15):

```
echo -n "Enter [y/n] : " ; read opt
```

OR! (Later is better)

```
read -p "[y/n]: " opt
```

Answer (score 4):

use -n handle in echo, that will avoid trailing newline

```
echo -n "Enter [y/n] : "
read opt
```